# VBA copy last row range and paste to another sheet

Tags: vba, spreadsheet, copy-paste

I am trying to find the last cell of column e.g. A then copy the whole row range which corresponds to that cell e.g. copy A5,B5,C5 etc and paste them to another sheet in specific row range e.g. A10,B10, C10 etc. Any help? thank you very much!

```
Sub Macro3() 
  Sheets("Stream").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Copy
  Sheets("General").Range("F2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,   Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Macro3() 
        Dim LastRowStream As Long, LastRowGeneral As Long,
        LastRowStream = Sheets("Stream").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Rows(LastRowStream & ":" & LastRowStream).EntireRow.copy

        LastRowGeneral = Sheets("General").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Sheets("General").Range("A" & LastRowGeneral).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,   Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though its not exactly what i need. I need to paste in specific row in the sheet General, not to the last empty row.

Comment: Also this code doesnt really work at all. It is pasting empty row in the Sheet General. Thanks